# Internal compiler error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 ... generateUnboxingConversion

Tags: java, boxing, autoboxing, unboxing

I got some weird exception when trying to compile this:

```
  Byte b = 2;
  if (b < new Integer(5)) {
     ...
  }
```

Is it a valid check (unboxing-implicit cast - unboxing)?

Comment: What version of java are you using? I just tested this on 1.6.0_17, and it works.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a bug in your compiler, here's what you do:

- Make sure you are using an up to date
  version of the compiler.
- If the vendor has a public bug database, check that (hint: use actual text copy-and-pasted from the exception trace).
- If it's a known bug, up vote it, raise an escalation, whatever.
- If you can't find a copy of the bug, submit a bug report with a concise, compilable (or not!) test case.

In general, it's not useful to post about random bugs in software products on Q&A sites.

Comment: If the compiler throws an exception, it is a bug in the compiler!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class test
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
Byte b = 2;
if( b < new Integer(5) )
{
System.out.println( "Working." );
}
}
}
```

Works for me. (Java 1.6.0_17).

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an Internal Compiler Error (ICE), it's a bug in the Java compiler itself, not necessarily anything wrong with your code.

Your code snippet compiles fine on a recent OpenJDK.  What Java compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

My compiler version used is: 1.6.0_16-b01 for 6.0 compliant
It looks like the problem disappears if I switch to 5.0 compliant code.

Comment: Can you compile Stafan Kendall's complete, concise example program?

Comment: From Stefan's response it sounds like it's already been fixed in a newer version (assuming you are both using the "normal" Sun javac).  If you're not using Sun's javac then I'd definitely follow Tom Hawtin's advice to get bug noticed by the vendor.

Comment: So it's a problem outside of the code you have quoted. Can you construct a simple example that fails?

Comment: I discovered the problem. If the line "System.out.println( "Working." );" is removed and the if is blank, then that exception is thrown. This throws the same exception:"int a=4;if (b > 2 && b < new Integer(a++)) {}"

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too, but no one(1.6 and 1.8) javac didn't got right. There were more than two libs(*.jar files), which is different versions of duplicated libs. Removing duplicates resolved comlie error